# KVM trying to restore from backup and getting error unexpected data

Tags: backup, kvm-virtualization, centos8, virsh

Hello I made a backup of a VM guest with these steps:

```
1. virsh dumpxml --migratable test > /backup/test.xml

2. virsh snapshot-create-as --domain test   \
                         --name backup.qcow2 \
                         --no-metadata       \
                         --atomic            \
                         --quiesce           \
                         --disk-only         \
                         --diskspec vda,snapshot=external

3. cp /var/lib/libvirt/images/test.qcow2 /backup/
4. virsh blockcommit test vda --active --pivot
5. rm -f /var/lib/libvirt/images/test.backup.qcow2
```

After backup I am trying to test if I can restore from it.

1. I am shutting down guest 'test'
2. Undefying guest 'test'
3. removing qcow2 image from main images folder
4. then copy qcow2 to main image folder
5. Trying to define by this command:

`virsh define -file /backup/test.xml`

and I am getting error: `error: unexpected data 'test.xml'`

What I am doing wrong? How can I troubleshot this?

Answer (score 1):

When you get an error suggesting a syntax problem, you should always check the man page first.

`virsh define` expects only one argument, the filename from which it should load the XML definition. You have passed *two* arguments. Thus it thinks you are trying to load a file named `-file`, and has no idea what you mean with the second argument `test.xml`.

The correct syntax is `virsh define filename`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your virsh define is, as Hampton said, you should either remove the option -file, or if you want to keep it, it should be double hyphen, not a single one. So, it should be --file.

Answer (score 0):

It works both ways:

```
virsh define --file /backup/test.xml
```

or

```
virsh define /backup/test.xml
```